# MSTest crash during a build in TFS 2008 SP1

Tags: tfs, mstest

I've never managed to make MsTest works during the build of my solution on TFS. When I look the build log, I see this that TFS want to execute MsTest :

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /nologo /searchpathroot:"C:\BinaryRoot\TFSBuild" /resultsfileroot:"C:\TestResults\" /testmetadata:"C:\Build\MySolution\Full.vsmdi" /testlist:"WorkingTest" ...
```

But the build don't create any test result file.
I tried to launch this line manually on the build server but MsTest crash after this :

> ```
> Loading C:\Build\MySolution\Full.vsmdi...
>
>   Search path(s) for tests:
>   C:\Build\MySolution\Binaries\TFSBuild
>   C:\Build\MySolution
>   Search path(s) for default run configuration:
>   C:\Build\MySolution
> ```

I don't see any problem with the path, my file testrunconfig is under C:\Build\MySolution.
My tests can run on my machine (VS 2008 vsts).
I've got the same problem with another build machine.

The event viewer, shows me two errors :

> NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3082 -
>   Fatal Execution Engine Error
>   (7A035FC0) (80131506)

and

```
Faulting application mstest.exe, version 9.0.30729.1, stamp 488f21a6, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3082, stamp 492b82c1, debug? 0, fault address 0x001c5fc0.
```

Does someone has an idea about this issue, or should I just switch to another test framework/CI server ? :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem with Hudson CI, so I don't think this is related to your CI server.

Still searching for a solution though...

Answer (score 0):

There is a hotfix for the same error signature, different conditions but it could be the same underlying cause - give [this](http://www.ninjacoding.net/archive/2009/04/02/hotfix-for-asp.net-mvc-visual-studio-crashes.aspx) a try.